# Invoking a web service in a Web API Project...in which layer to invoke?

Tags: c#, web-services, .net-4.5, asp.net-web-api

I am using **Microsoft ASP.NET Web API 2** and one of my end points has to internally invoke a legacy non-Microsoft web service (not `asmx` or `svc`) .

Which layer should I invoke this in?

I currently have :
**Repository layer:**  where all the CRUD calls to DB are done now.

**Domain Manager:** where respective manager classes invoke the **Repository Layer** methods.

And my **Web API Controller** methods invoke the respective **Domain Manager** methods.

Should I just have another method in my **Repository Layer** which invokes the web service? And follow the usual pattern above?

Comment: This might be a good question for [programmers.se], but I don't think it's a good question for here.

Answer (score 2):

If we adhere to [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29) principles, the choice becomes a bit clearer:

1. **Repository Layer:** Violates 'S' in [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_%28object-oriented_design%29), having to modify the repository class(es) due to changes in the web service endpoint smells.
2. **Domain Manager:** *Possibly*
3. **WebAPI Controller:** This makes the most sense to me.  No need to over-abstract something that won't be reused.  If the web service is consumed from multiple WebAPI actions, then the domain manager might make more sense.